# Isolate column in R from text file

Tags: r

I want to analyze market data that is being saved in a text file. 
The data consists of "Date Time;Price;Size". I want to only look at the Sizes, how can I separate this data in R so that I may do statistical analysis on the sizes?

Example:

```
20170918 040001;50.42;1
20170918 040002;50.42;1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `read.csv` with semicolon as a delimeter:

```
df <- read.csv(file="path/to/your/file.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)
```

The sizes can be accessed using `df$Sizes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` argument of `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#[[1L]] extracts the column of the temporary table to a vector;
#  you could also use $V2, but this _may_ not be perfectly robust
price = fread('/path/to/file'select = 2L)[[1L]]
```

`fread` should be able to detect automatically that your file doesn't have headers, as well as that the field separator is `;`. If not, set `header = FALSE` and/or `sep = ';'`.

---

Of course, it's not likely that you will *only* use the vector of prices *independently of the rest of the data*. So you should really just store the whole data file in a `data.table`:

```
market_data = fread('/path/to/file', col.names = c('date_time', 'price', 'size'))
```

Then you can manipulate `market_data` as you would any `data.table` (see [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)), e.g.

```
market_data[ , mean(price)]
market_data[ , sd(price)]
```

and so on.

Comment: No it does not have headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=read.table("your file")


size=df[4]
```

your sizes data will be in size as a data frame